# Core Plot: Multiple colors for scatter plot fill area

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, core-plot

Basically I need to fill plot's area with 2 colours. I found some hints to use 2 plots, but in my case I have a lot of data, and I will need to draw hundreds or even thousands of plots, some of them will have color 1, another will have color 2. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two plots to have two different fills. Return `nil` or `[NSNull null]` from the datasource to leave gaps in the plots where you want the other plot to take over.